# how to add correlation value and p-values in boxplot in R

Tags: r

I want to add a computed correlation coefficient and p-value to my boxplot. This is my code:

```
# Load needed package
library(coin)

# Simulate data
xx <- runif(10)
yy <- runif(10)

# Compute R and p-value
scor <- cor(xx, yy, method = "spearman")
ppp <- spearman_test(xx ~ yy)

# Make plot
boxplot(list(t(xx),t(yy)), main="exprment values", col = c("orange", "yellow"))
legend("topright", bty="n", legend=paste("r=0.69, p=0.0001"))
```

I want the R and p-value to be printed automatically so I don't have to type them out.

Comment: It makes very little sense to plot a boxplot with p-values from a correlation estimate. A scatterplot would be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste character and numeric values together as you've tried, just need to be in the right format.

```
legend("topright", bty="n", legend=paste("r=", scor, ", p=", ppp, sep = ""))
```

Comment: Note that you will want to use the `round` function, otherwise `paste` is going to output a ton of digits. So you will want to do something like `paste("r=", round(scor,2), ", p=", round(ppp,2), sep = "")`

Comment: Thanks , actually, ppp is not single value , its like this..    >ppp                                                                                                 Asymptotic Spearman Correlation Test

data:  xx by yy
Z = -0.6, p-value = 0.5485
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0                                                                                                                         and I want only pvalue to print on plot,

Comment: @mona then extract the attribute from the result object, using the `$` operator.